# It seems RACObserve doesn't work well

Tags: ios, reactive-cocoa

I used RACObserve to create a signal but it doesn't work well while rac_textSignal is ok.
Here is my code:

```
[RACObserve(self, searchText.text); subscribeNext: ^(id newName){
    NSLog(@"newName:%@", newName);
}];
[self.searchText.rac_textSignal subscribeNext: ^(id newName){
    NSLog(@"newName:%@", newName);
}];
```

When the app is run, both signal print out the newName with a nil value.But every time I change the text in the text field, only the second signl will work and print the latest text in the text value. The first signal never print anything.

Comment: `RACObserve` only works for key-value compliant properties, of which `UITextVIew` and `UITextField`'s `text` are not (hence the inclusion of the `rac_textSignal` helpers).

Comment: Got it. Thank you very much. But how can I know whether a property is key-value compliant?

Comment: :( As far as I know, it's pure folklore. *Some* libraries -- and I mean a tiny fraction -- explicitly document KVO-compliance for properties. Others assume all properties are KVO-compliant. Others assume none are. Within `UIKit`, you should assume that *no* properties are KVO-compliant. Even if it works now, a future version of iOS might remove that property. It just happens to work "by accident" with some properties.

Comment: (Most classes in UIKit will provide an alternate means of observing "interesting" information though, like delegation or target/action, and it's easy to make RAC wrappers for those cases when they aren't already built-in to ReactiveCocoa.)

Answer (score 1):

```
RACSignal * searchSignal = [RACSignal merge:@[RACObserve(self.searchTextfield, text), self. searchTextfield.rac_textSignal]];
```

`searchSignal` will be fire with any of `searchTextField` changes - in code with `searchField.text` property or with user.